# Ajax in Rails 5 throw "ActionController::UnknownFormat " error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to implement a search method that will automaticaly populate a form through the use of Ajax.

I have a simple_form_form that is feed with a collection of Client instance. Once I select a client, a js code submit the form and then goes to the corresponded controller method.
This part is working, but when the code hits the Client#search it stops at my "respond_to |format|" line. Stating that this is an unknown format.

I looked differents stackover posts, but I could'nt find any concrete answers.

Thanks,

here is the code:

My error:

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhq3C.png)

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  class OnlyAjaxRequest
    def matches?(request)
      request.xhr?
      # raise
    end
  end
  get 'search', to: 'invoices#search', as: 'search', constraint: OnlyAjaxRequest.new

end
```

formSubmit.js

```
let clientOption = document.querySelector('#search_client');
const form = document.querySelector('.search');   
clientOption.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
 form.submit(); 
})
```

Client Controller:

```
  def search
    if params[:search]
      @client_found = Client.find(params[:search][:client]) if Client.find(params[:search][:client]).present?
      respond_to do |format|
        #format.html {}
        format.js { render :search}
      end
    end
  end
```

Search.js.erb

```
console.log('hello');
$('#ajx-cli').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'invoices/invoice_new_partial/find_client')%>");
```

Client Selection Form

```
<%= simple_form_for :search, url: search_path, remote: true, method: :get, html: { id: :find_cli } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :client, label:"Sélectionnez un client", collection: @my_clients, label_method: :company_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: true, as: :select %>
<% end %>
```

Updated Form

```
<div id='ajx-cli'>
  <%= f.fields_for :client  do |client| %>
    <%= render partial: "invoices/invoice_new_partial/oneoff_client",locals: {f: client, client_found: @client_found}  %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Also, my search action seems to be processed as html instead of js.

Logs terminal

```
Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bclient%5D=176" for ::1 at 2020-10-17 14:15:07 +0200
Processing by InvoicesController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"client"=>"176"}}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 92], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/utilisateur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Invoice Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "invoices" WHERE (due_date < '2020-10-17') AND "invoices"."status" != $1 LIMIT $2  [["status", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:32
  Invoice Update All (0.9ms)  UPDATE "invoices" SET "status" = 4 WHERE (due_date < '2020-10-17') AND "invoices"."status" != $1  [["status", 3]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:34
  Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 176], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:56
  CACHE Client Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 176], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:56
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:58:in `search'
```

**EDIT**

Trying to force format didn't work either. My request was correctly processed as JS, so I didn't have the same error, but my `search.js.erb` was rendered instead of being executed.

New Invoice#search

```
  def search
    if params[:search]
      @client_found = Client.find(params[:search][:client]) if Client.find(params[:search][:client]).present?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render  layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript'}
      end
    end
```

New Client Selection Form

```
  <%= simple_form_for :search, url: search_path(format: :js), remote: true, method: :get, html: { id: :find_cli } do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "invoices/invoice_new_partial/client_selection",locals: {my_clients: @my_clients, f: f, client_found: @client_found} %>
  <% end %>
```

Logs:

```
Started GET "/search.js?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bclient%5D=178" for ::1 at 2020-10-17 19:19:43 +0200
Processing by InvoicesController#search as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"client"=>"178"}}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 92], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/utilisateur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Invoice Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "invoices" WHERE (due_date < '2020-10-17') AND "invoices"."status" != $1 LIMIT $2  [["status", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:32
  Invoice Update All (6.5ms)  UPDATE "invoices" SET "status" = 4 WHERE (due_date < '2020-10-17') AND "invoices"."status" != $1  [["status", 3]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:34
  Client Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 178], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:56
  CACHE Client Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 178], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:56
  Rendering invoices/search.js.erb
  Rendered invoices/invoice_new_partial/_find_client.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered invoices/search.js.erb (2.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 5.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)
```

Comment: If the request is being sent as `text/html` then the most likely reason is that you have not included the Rails UJS driver in the javascript on your page or have errors that is preventing it from working. Look at the logs/terminal where you are running rails to see the request type and *add that information to the question by editing*. You can also check the network tab in the browser. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @max , I thought that the sole purpose adding the parameter `remote:true` to a form, was to ensure that request would only be a Js request. Also I have no errors  in the Console, and I do have `//= require rails-ujs` included in my `Application.js`.  
I updated my question, thanks for the help.

Comment: `remote: true` does nothing without the JavaScript event handler that makes it actually send XHR requests.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't wrapped my mind around why my js.erb was rendered as a plain text, instead of being executed, so I started over.
I updated my form Submit.js and it worked like a charm.

New routes.rb

```
post 'search', to: 'invoices#search', as: 'search'
```

New Client Selection form

```
<%= simple_form_for :search, remote: true, html: { id: :find_cli } do |f| %>
        <%= render partial: "invoices/invoice_new_partial/client_selection",locals: {my_clients: @my_clients, f: f, client_found: @client_found} %>
      <% end %>
```

New formSubmit.js

```
let clientOption = document.querySelector('#search_client');
  const form = document.querySelector('.search');
  clientOption.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    let selector = document.querySelector('#search_client')
    let client = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
    Rails.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: `/search?utf8=✓&search%5Bclient%5D=${client}`,
      headers: {
          accept: '*/*',
          'X-CSRF-Token': Rails.csrfToken()
        }
    });
  });
```